# Two full screen floats with border

Tags: css, css-float, multiple-columns

I am designing a website with two floating columns which I want to fill the whole screen.

```
#column_main{ 
      position:relative;
      background:#ffffff;
      float:left;
      width:70%;
      height:auto;
      min-height:550px;
}
#column_side{
     position:relative;
     background:#dbdada;
     float:left;
     width:30%;
     height:auto;
     min-height:550px;
}
```

if I had the line below to #column_main

```
 border-left:solid 1px #c0c1c4;
```

The float messes up and they are no longer side by side.

In IE I have been able to fix the problem by setting the #column_main width to auto and it fills the rest of the page. This doesn't work in firefox and I have tried reducing the percentage slightly but that leaves a gap between the #column_main and the right edge of the page. Is there a way to have the 1px border on the left and make the float fill the remainder of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The float no longer works because of the box model where the border is added to the width instead of included in the width, you have already used up 100% of the width by doing width:70% and width: 30%.

If you plan on applying a border you might want to apply it to a child element inside one of the wrapping floated columns and use those parent columns only as a grid system to structure your other content.

Alternatively try [bootstrap grids](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 0):

add `box-sizing: border-box;` to #column_main

This property basically says you want the box size to apply to the border and everything inside it.

[This blog post](http://www.justinbar.net/post/floated-divs-going-under-eachother-and-not-side-by-side) explains this, and some other options to fix this particular problem.